# Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent in Angular

Tags: angular

Angualar Register Component Error

using following Angular Register component in user registration
register.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : submitted && f.name.errors}">

            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.name.errors.required">
                    Name is Required
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

then when I ring Angular ng serve run command it is occuring following error messages as well

```
Error: src/app/register/register.component.html:9:155 - error TS4111: Property 'name' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['name'].

9             <input type="text" formControlName="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' :
submitted && f.name.errors}">
  
               ~~~~

  src/app/register/register.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.


Error: src/app/register/register.component.html:11:40 - error TS4111: Property 'name' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['name'].

11             <div *ngIf="submitted && f.name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                                          ~~~~

  src/app/register/register.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.


Error: src/app/register/register.component.html:12:31 - error TS4111: Property 'name' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['name'].

12                 <div *ngIf="f.name.errors.required">
                                 ~~~~

  src/app/register/register.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.


Error: src/app/register/register.component.html:12:43 - error TS4111: Property 'required' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['required'].

12                 <div *ngIf="f.name.errors.required">
                                             ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/register/register.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.
```

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try changing from direct property access to accessing it via quotes, that is what the error is saying to correct!

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : submitted && f?.['name']?.['errors']}">

        <div *ngIf="submitted && f?.['name']?.['errors']" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f?.['name']?.['errors']?.['required']">
                Name is Required
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

#### References

1. [Property 'fName' comes from an index signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106472/property-fname-comes-from-an-index-signature-so-it-must-be-accessed-with-fn)

Comment: not work for me

Comment: @beoi Could you share a basic example of it working on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vui1m3) replicating the issue!

Comment: did you mean code paste on stackblitz?

Comment: @beoi Could you try getting the error on stackblitz so that it can be checked?

Comment: how could I export my codes here? just copy and paste enough?

Comment: occured following error msg `Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.`

Comment: @beoi my bad, hope this fixes your issue, updated my answer!

Comment: now it is working but occured following warning msg `warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be safely removed.`

Comment: `<input type="text" formControlName="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' :
submitted && f?.['name']?.['errors']}">`

Comment: @beoi please remove the `?.` wherever necessary to close this issue!

Comment: all ? should be removed

Comment: @beoi Since I am not able to view the angular output, please do trial and error and add/remove the `?.` until the errors resolve! If I am seeing the same output as you, I would resolve it easily, but unfortunately I cant!

Answer (score 0):

Try access name prop with square bracket:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    formControlName="name"
    name="name"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter Name"
    [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f['name'].errors}"
  />

  <div *ngIf="submitted && f['name'].errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f['name'].errors.required">
      Name is Required
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```